# Java private method 'return' or 'set value'

Tags: java

Should my private method return a value or set it directly ?
Is there a benefit one way or the other and if so why?

This is my code:

```
public class MinorMatrix {

int[][] minorMatrix;
int determinant;
int matrixSize;

public MinorMatrix(int a, int b, int[][] matrix) {
    matrixSize = matrix.length;
    createMinorMatrix(a, b, matrix);
    createDetermiant();

}

private void createDetermiant() {

    // Do this (with return):
    return value;
    // or with void
    determinant = value;
}
}
```

Comment: Definitely without question return the value.  Storing state in class variables is just silly.

Comment: This question belongs on Programmers Stack Exchange.

Comment: @MichaelEaster when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @MichaelEaster and why? Isnt Stack Overflow for Programming Questions?

Comment: @cricket_007 You can `return;` in a `void` method, you just can't `return something;`.

Comment: @gdejohn I am aware. I was referring to the posted code.

Comment: @cricket_007 Anyone who's unaware would probably draw the wrong conclusion from your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you should return values, the void style here produces a side-effect. It *may* be *marginally* more efficient to use side-effects but in many cases (and this is one) it makes the flow of the program harder to follow.

Use a return, not a void, because then any maintainers don't have to investigate your `createDeterminant()` method, they can trust it as a black box. If you use a side effect, future users don't know how to get the value that is created. The only way to find out is to investigate the function which adds unnecessary work.